# E2E test passed the local run but failed in Jenkins (protractor and jasmine 2)

Tags: selenium, testing, jenkins, automation, protractor

We have e2e test integrated with Jenkins system. For a few weeks this test successfully ran both, locally and from Jenkins (as a part of the build pipeline).

At the end of Sprint, I modified the script to reflect Sprint changes and made sure it passed locally. Then, I merged the changes with master. Now, e2e runs from Jenkins are failing 100% of the time, while when I locally connect to QA envs there is no problem.

The error I am getting is - Element is not clickable at point (x, y) which I cannot reproduce locally.

The server doesn't have a real screen so I cannot go out there and see what's going on. Resolutions are perfectly matching. I have other people running this test locally and there is no problem.

What could possibly cause these failures and how do I troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Even, I have faced the same situation many times. So what you need to do is, try with different locator strategy for the element where it got failed and implement the scripts which uses protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele) whevere you feel it may get failed.

Comment: Were you using phantomjs or chrome headless ? I would recomend to use scrollTo(x,y) and see if that helps, sometimes i had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its a question from **1000ft** and pretty difficult to identify where exactly the issue could be but I listed down some probable causes/debugging tips that could help you

1.Whats your **checkout strategy** from source code repository? Check job workspace and it should have the most recent code and check if its indeed the latest one.
May be configure Job to always pick a new version instead of 'update'

2.Add a reporter based on the test framework you are using especially the ones which provide **screenshots**. Refer my [blog](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/08/04/first-blog-post/) for more details -

3.Check the stack trace of your error from Jenkins console report and verify the exact trigerring point